# make css group checkbox work independently

Tags: html, css

i copied a checkbox code from [codepen](http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm). it works perfectly after i change it to my preference but the problem is, the check box works if its one alone ( *only one checks if its above one* ). is there any way to make ecah of them work independently without changing the classes and id's each time i need it. [**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zL8wjazz/)

HTML

```
<div class="roundedOne">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedOne" name="check" />
      <label for="roundedOne"></label>
</div>
 <div class="roundedOne">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedOne" name="check" />
      <label for="roundedOne"></label>
</div>

    <div class="roundedOne">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedOne" name="check" />
      <label for="roundedOne"></label>
</div>

    <div class="roundedOne">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedOne" name="check" />
      <label for="roundedOne"></label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.roundedOne {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fcfff4;
  border: 2px solid #77c100;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.roundedOne label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 14.5px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  background: #77c100;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.roundedOne label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.roundedOne input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.roundedOne input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your checkboxes have the same ID. And your label's `for=""` are all pointing to the same id. Make them different and that should fix your issue. Your IDs have to be different. You can only have the one instance of a particular ID on a given page

Comment: so i have to change the labels and IDs?

Comment: Yeah, each set of input and label `for=""` need to have their own ID

Comment: Regarding unique IDs: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F77.html

Answer (score 3):

You're issue is with having multiple uses of ID.

The:

```
<label for="roundedOne"></label>
```

is looking for an input with the id="roundedOne".

Since all of your inputs share that ID it will go to the first one.
Try adding a unique ID to each input, and changing the labels to match, and that should solve your issue.

[Here's a fiddle of the above changes.](http://jsfiddle.net/zL8wjazz/2/)